# Encrypted SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, encryption

I'm looking for encrypted SQL database, I'm going to install it on client's machines, and I don't want client to database directly.

I know this is not 100% secure, and I'm not interested in SQL Server, SQLite or Oracle.

If you know any solutions of this kind please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: don't store anything on a client's system that you don't want the client to access. a locked box is useless if the keys are siting on top.

Comment: I'm aware if it, but it is not mine decision. I'm just looking for appropriate solution.

Comment: Any reasons why you are not interested in SQLite or SQL Server (Compact Edition I suppose) ? Which parts does not interest you in them? Is it a business decision? What features are you looking for in the product ?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray: SQLite - concurent access, SQL CE - Doesn't support Linux servers. I know they support encryption, I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: I'm running sqlite db on linux server, why do you think you can't ?

Comment: @Louis SQLite - is not good with concurrent access. SQL CE - Doesn't support Linux servers. I want concurrent access and Linux support.

Comment: SQL Server CE and SQLite were not built with concurrent access in mind. They are not supposed to be accessed like such because they are recommended for single user access data storage for a mobile phone application. Why not use `MySQL` then? I think it supports both Windows and Linux, it's free, open source and can support concurrent access to data.

Comment: You realise that you won't be able to get completely secure encryption, most applications (I mean your application not the database) can be reverse engineered enough to at least get the decryption details out. What's wrong with using any SQL database and just holding all the usernames and passwords yourself? Are you worried that they will open the database file in a text editor and read the data out?  Do you want to prevent them from reading it or from changing it?

Comment: @Seph basic requirement is to prevent client from reading data from database directly - without using application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements, I suggest you use `MySQL`. It supports both Windows and Linux. It's free and open source and has concurrency support. Also it has [cryptography support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

One more idea: You can use any kind of DB and encrypt/decrypt data upon saving/retrieving. This way, you are not required to investigate databases with encryption support. You will be handling this operation to your programming language, most common languages have the capability to deal with encryption and decryotion.